# How to have image and text side by side

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to have the [as shown in picture] , facebook icon and text side by side. I cannot able to get that clearly.

My tried code

**CSS**

```
 .iconDetails {
 margin-left:2%;
float:left; 
height:40px;
width:40px; 
} 

.container2 {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:1%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='container2'>
        <div>
            <img src='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png' class='iconDetails'>
        </div>  
    <div style='margin-left:60px;'>
    <h4>Facebook</h4>
    <div style="font-size:.6em">fine location, GPS, coarse location</div>
    <div style="float:right;font-size:.6em">0 mins ago</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMdfC/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your h4 has some crazy margin on it, so remove it

```
h4 {
    margin:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qMdfC/2/

edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/qMdfC/6/

for the 0 minutes text, added a float left to the first div, but personally i'd just combine them, although you may have reasons not to.

Comment: "0 mins ago" text is coming down, check again

Comment: @Lonely as the div is set to float right check http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/s3Qye/

Comment: @Lonely added the fix for that, but it may be a better idea to merge the two divs, and have the minutes contained in a span. It depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Actually the styles are really wrong, just setting the margin for `h4` wont solve, as he has uncleared floats, leading the parent element not to expand, also, he needs to restructure his HTML so I don't know whether users went straight for the fiddle but the CSS is completely wrong here

Comment: The "px" is redundant. It should be: `margin:0;`

Answer (score 6):

You're already doing it correctly, it just that the `<h4>Facebook</h4>` tag is taking too much vertical margin. You can remove it by using the style `margin:0px` on the `<h4>` tag.

For your future convenience, you can put border (`border:1px solid black`) on your elements to see which part you actually get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on border.

Answer (score 2):

It's always worth grouping elements into sections that are relevant.
In your case, a parent element that contains two columns;

1. icon
2. text.

http://jsfiddle.net/qMdfC/10/

HTML:

```
<div class='container2'>
    <img src='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png' class='iconDetails' />

    <div class="text">
        <h4>Facebook</h4>
        <p>
            fine location, GPS, coarse location
            <span>0 mins ago</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.iconDetails {
    margin:0 2%;
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
}
.container2 {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:1%;
}
.text {
    float:left;
}
.text h4, .text p {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    font-size:0.6em;
}
.text p span {
    color:#666;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following code : jsfiddle.net/KqHEC/

**HTML**

```
<div class='container2'>
        <div class="left">
            <img src='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png' class='iconDetails'>
        </div>  
    <div   class="right" >
    <h4>Facebook</h4>
    <div style="font-size:.7em;width:160px;float:left;">fine location, GPS, coarse location</div>
    <div style="float:right;font-size:.7em">0 mins ago</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.iconDetails {
 margin-left:2%;
float:left; 
height:40px;
width:40px; 
} 

.container2 {
    width:270px;
    height:auto;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
}
h4{margin:0}
.left {float:left;width:45px;}
.right {float:left;margin:0 0 0 5px;width:215px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KqHEC/1/

Answer (score 1):

remove the margin for the h4 tag

```
h4 {
margin:0px;
}
```

Fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/s3Qye/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class='containerBox'>
    <div>
       <img src='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png' class='iconDetails'>
       <div>
       <h4>Facebook</h4>  
       <div style="font-size:.6em;float:left; margin-left:5px;color:white;">fine location, GPS, coarse location</div>
       <div style="float:right;font-size:.6em; margin-right:5px; color:white;">0 mins ago</div>
       </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .iconDetails {
 margin-left:2%;
 float:left; 
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 } 

.containerBox {
width:300px;
height:60px;
padding:1px;
background-color:#303030;
}
h4{
margin:0px;
margin-top:3%;
margin-left:50px;
color:white;
}
```