# Make this image on the left of the text with the text on top or in the center?

Tags: html, css, image, text

I've been looking on the internet for a long time to get an image on the left of text, with the text on the top or on the center of the div. I've looked on a lot of posts on the internet, [How to have image and text side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567708/how-to-have-image-and-text-side-by-side), [Cant figure out how to have image and text side by side in a div and keep it responsive, fiddle included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170997/cant-figure-out-how-to-have-image-and-text-side-by-side-in-a-div-and-keep-it-res) and quite a few others.

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="logo1.png" alt="LimitMove Logo"> </img>
    <h1> Limit Move </h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a,a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active{
    color: #3C3C3C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,a:active{
    color:#4D4D4D;
}

h1{
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #DFDFDF;
}

#header{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: rgb(0,120,170);
}

#header img{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

#header h1, #header > #navbar{
    display: inline;
    text-align: text-top;

}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eed6pb9p/)

You can see that the text is at the bottom of the #header div tag, And I can't get it to the top.
I tried using padding-top:-20px; same with margin, but neither of them work properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `img` is a void element, it doesn't require a separate closing tag `</img>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#header h1, #header > #navbar{
    display: inline;
    text-align: text-top;
}
```

`text-top` is not a valid value for `text-align` (and text-align is for *horizontal* alignment).

You want to use `vertical-align` here, same as you did with the image; and you want to use `top` for both.

http://jsfiddle.net/eed6pb9p/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `align="left"` attribute in your image.

**E.g.**

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/lpJjofK.png" alt="LimitMove Logo"  align="left" />
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/eed6pb9p/1/).**

**It's easy and cleaner right?**

Hope it helps.

Comment: The align attribute is deprecated, and not supported in HTML5. The OP is already using a CSS stylesheet, we should not encourage switching to inline CSS.

Comment: It's not really deprecated. Check this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_attributes.htm

Comment: It's included in the html5 'Standard Attributes'.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? It was already deprecated in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-align-IMG).

Comment: I added a check this link above. I just search that in google. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_attributes.htm

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I'm not going to accept the answer yet, if it is deprecated.